# Failed to Parse JSON Response

Tags: android, json

I have JSON Response like this.I have tried a lot but unable to parse the Values.

This one is my Actual Response...

```
{"ResponseCode":"000","ResponseDescription":"Successful","SystemServiceID":["0000"],"SystemServiceName":["Test"],"ProductID":["000"],"ProductName":["Test"],"ProductDescription":["Test product"],"MinimumValue":[10000],"MaximumValue":[500000],"ImageURL":[null],"Country":["AAAA"],"CompanyID":["1"],"CompanyName":["Test"],"FieldLevel":["2"],"FieldInfo":["{\"Field1\":{\"Field Name\":\"Phone Number\",\"Field Type\":\"Number\",\"Validation\":{\"Min\":\"4\",\"Max\":\"8\"}},\"Field2\":{\"Field Name\":\"Email\",\"Field Type\":\"String\",\"Validation\":{\"Regular Expression\":\"abcd\",\"Min Length\":\"10\",\"Max Length\":\"20\"}}}"]}
```

Out of this i am able to parse all the field expect the below one...

```
{
    "Field1":
    {
            "Field Name":"Phone Number",
            "Field Type":"Number",
            "Validation":{"Min":"4","Max":"8"}
    },

    "Field2":
    {
            "Field Name":"Email",
            "Field Type":"String",
            "Validation":{"Regular Expression":"abcd","Min Length":"10","Max Length":"20"}
    }
}
```

I also want to fetch the value of `Validation":{"Min":"4","Max":"8"}` this field.Like it has max value 4 and min value is 8.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance ... :)

Comment: and if possible logcat too

Comment: I hope that you don't have that line breaks in the filenames in your real response. That would break it.

Comment: is it full response from server or you have just copy some of them ans paste here, ?

Comment: This is not a valid json

Comment: @PankajKumar Refer the updated question....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code to read Min And Max values

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(Json_String); 

JSONObject field1 = parentObject.getJSONObject("Field1"); 
JSONObject validation = field1.getJSONObject("Validation"); 

String min = validation.getString("Min"); 
String max = validation.getString("Max");
```

Assuming your JSON string is well formed.

Since in your response you are not getting the `"\"` into JSON so you need to some modifications into that like (update : It seems that replacement not required here)

```
String json = "{\"Field1\":{\"Field Name\":\"Phone Number\",\"Field Type\":\"Number\",\"Validation\":{\"Min\":\"4\",\"Max\":\"8\"}},\"Field2\":{\"Field Name\":\"Email\",\"Field Type\":\"String\",\"Validation\":{\"Regular Expression\":\"abcd\",\"Min Length\":\"10\",\"Max Length\":\"20\"}}}";

// json.replace("\\", ""); // I verified that parsing works well without replacement too

try {
     JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json);
     JSONObject field1 = parentObject.getJSONObject("Field1"); 
     JSONObject validation = field1.getJSONObject("Validation"); 

     String min = validation.getString("Min"); 
     String max = validation.getString("Max");

     System.out.println("Min :::::::  " + min);
     System.out.println("MAx ::::::: " + max);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Your line json.replace("\\", ""); does nothingin this example.

Comment: @rekire yes you are correct. I verified that and updated my answer. Thanks alot to correct me. thanks again